# How to make Django search contains work with uppercase and lowercase?

Tags: python, django

I have problem with Django `Example.objects.filter(text__contains='text here')` that only match with same input.

I want the search `contains` feature also works in uppercase and lowercase.

I have tried to use `Example.objects.filter(text__contains__iexact='text here')` and `Example.objects.filter(text__iexact__contains='text here')` but it's not work.

I found another way to search data in database form https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/search/ but it's just for PostgreSQL user.

Is there any solution to search for data from the database without using Django 'raw' MySQL query?

Comment: have you tried `text__icontains`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `icontains` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains

```
Entry.objects.get(headline__icontains='Lennon')
```